# Python MySQL, 1064 (42000), "You have an error in your SQL syntax;..."

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

This's my table `test_table`:

id name
1  aa
2  bb
3  cc

I get the message when it’s run with python3:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test as(SELECT * from test_table)  SELECT name FROM test' at line 1

this is my syntax:

```
cnxn = mysql.connector.connect(**sql_config)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = """
           with test as(SELECT * FROM `test_table`)  
           SELECT * FROM test
        """
cursor.execute(query)
get_data = cursor.fetchall()
cnxn.close()
cursor.close()
```

***The bug may be in syntax of query.***

Because I tried the following two methods with without error:

1.Sequel Ace: use 'with'

```
with `test` as ( SELECT * FROM `test_table`)
SELECT `name` FROM `test`
```

2.python3: not used ‘with’ and can work

```
query = """
           SELECT name FROM test_table
        """
```

How do I modify 'with as' of syntax?

```
query = """
          with test as(SELECT * FROM test_table)  
          SELECT * FROM test
        """
```

Comment: What mysql version are you on? What does "select @@version" return?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure you're on an old version of mysql. The Common table expression feature (that one with "with") was introduce only in version 8.

Every version below 8 will return you exact same error message. See first [db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2N3Yv2gy7UZD2vBTCJvai/1)

Whereas the same query runs perfect starting from version 8 as you may seen on the second [db_fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7eaHSYeT1Hqawd34kxE5dj/0)

But that's not the end. The CTE can be replaced with a subquery like this

```
SELECT name FROM (select 'XXX' name) q;
```

or, in case, if you need to join:

```
select x.name
  FROM (select 'XXX' name) x
  JOIN (select 'XXX' name union all select 'YYY') y
    ON x.name = y.name;
```

as you can see on [third db_fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/meqj5exzdraxDyqwhNs6uo/0)